# Android Databinding is not working with androidX

Tags: android, android-databinding, androidx

I'm trying new android x library which replaced old appCompat library in android. And I faced one problem. I want to load image on recyclerView item and for that I want to use databinding. Here's my code

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                app:loadImageFromNetwork="@{car.model.photoUrl}" <- here I'm using binding class
                android:id="@+id/appCompatImageView"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and here my binding class

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide

object Bindings {
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("loadImageFromNetwork")
    fun loadImageFromNetwork(imageView: AppCompatImageView, url: String) {
        Glide.with(imageView.context).load(url).into(imageView)
    }
}
```

And I'm getting this error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
  ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:loadImageFromNetwork' with parameter type java.lang.String on android.widget.ImageView.
  file:S:\Downloads\ppp\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\layout\car_item_view.xml
  loc:26:44 - 26:61
  ****\ data binding error ****
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

EDIT I also have this in my `gradle.properties` file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Here's my Car class

```
data class Car(val id:  Int, val plateNumber: String, val location: Location, val model: Model)

data class Model(val id: Int, val title: String, val photoUrl: String)
```

Comment: what is your `car.model.photoUrl` here in xml?

Comment: It is a string that contains url for a image
I also tried to hardcode url but still same happens.

Comment: issue is that, your binding adapter method is in object & that's why it's failed to find it. Put it in some class and use that class as variable in xml for binding.

Comment: I changed adapter method so now it accept  Car object and I pass a car in my xml but I get the same error.

Comment: Have you had any success in finding a solution to this problem? I have the same problem in a new project where I'm also using the X library.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler failed to find method `loadImageFromNetwork()`, because it's added inside **object**, so consider placing it inside a class like:

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide

class Bindings {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @BindingAdapter("loadImageFromNetwork")
        fun loadImageFromNetwork(imageView: AppCompatImageView, url: String) {
            Glide.with(imageView.context).load(url).into(imageView)
        }
    }
}
```

and you're good to go with that class.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work for me. I have other app where I don't use androidx but support lib and on that project biindings works as expected. Don't you think that it's androidx bug?

Comment: I don't think so, because i've already done it with **androidx** like this, otherwise there must be other serious issue with you if it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class CarViewModel(var car: Car, val context: Context) {

fun getImageCar() = car.model.photoUrl

companion object {
    @JvmStatic @BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
    fun setImageUrl(imageView: ImageView, url: String) {
        Glide.with(imageView.context).load(url).into(imageView)
    }
  }
}
```

in your XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable name="carViewModel"
              type="your.package.CarViewModel"/>
</data>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_notice"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                app:imageUrl="@{carViewModel.imageNotice}"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

It works for me, you need to obtain URL first and then databinding puts your URL into imageView. I'm using androidX too, not for image but the rest of components